# Terraform conditional nested attribute

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

What's the correct syntax to condition a nested attribute in terraform ? For example `serverlessv2_scaling_configuration` in the config below :

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
    max_capacity = 128.0
    min_capacity = 0.5
  }
}
```

Goal is to be able to create [serverless](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster#serverlessv2_scaling_configuration-argument-reference) or non-serverless RDS depending of an environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Terraform [dynamic block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) syntax for that, with a list of size 1 or 0. Assuming `var.serverless` is a boolean input variable:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  dynamic "serverlessv2_scaling_configuration" {
    for_each = var.serverless ? [1] : []
    content {
      max_capacity = 128.0
      min_capacity = 0.5
    }
  }
}
```